# How does the spread syntax affect array splice

Tags: javascript, arrays, spread-syntax

I found the following code and I don't know what is the difference between A and B:

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
```

A

```
fruits.splice(2,0,["Lemon", "Kiwi"]);
```

B

```
fruits.splice(...[2,0].concat(["Lemon", "Kiwi"]));
```

```js
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
var A = fruits.splice(2, 0, ["Lemon", "Kiwi"]);
var B = fruits.splice(...[2, 0].concat(["Lemon", "Kiwi"]));

console.log(A)
console.log(B)
```

Comment: You should go through with splice operator concept https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp -@vuvu

Comment: You Can show `splice` Properties from here https://lorenstewart.me/2017/01/22/javascript-array-methods-mutating-vs-non-mutating/

Comment: It seems this is really more about the spread operator than the splice.

Comment: You'd notice the difference if you logged `fruits` after each operation instead of logging `A` and `B`.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

First of all, Statement A & Statement B will generate **different** results.

In `Statement A`, you are inserting an array (`["Lemon", "Kiwi"]`) as an array element at position 2 while removing 0 items. So, you are inserting a string array in another string array at position 2.

```js
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];


fruits.splice(2,0,["Lemon", "Kiwi"]);

console.log(fruits);
```

**However**, `Statement B` is much more interesting. To, understand it fully, first log out it's core portion like this:

```js
console.log(...[2,0].concat(["Lemon", "Kiwi"]));  // basic array concatenation then spread
```

As you can see it generates, `2 0 Lemon Kiwi`. Then it is passed as parameter to `fruits.splice(..here..)`. According to [`array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) it will enter two strings (Lemon & Kiwi) at position 2, while removing 0 elements.

```js
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];

fruits.splice(...[2,0].concat(["Lemon", "Kiwi"]));
// is same as fruits.splice(2, 0, 'Lemon', 'Kiwi')

console.log(fruits);
```

NOTE:

- [`array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) **updates the original array**.
- `Statement A` inserts an **`array`** (IE `["Lemon", "Kiwi"]`) in parent string array whereas, `Statement B` inserts **two strings** (IE `'Lemon', 'Kiwi'`) in parent string array.

Answer (score 11):

A treats `["Lemon", "Kiwi"]` as one item and inserts it in given index

```
["Banana", "Orange", ["Lemon", "Kiwi"], "Apple" , "Mango"];
```

B concats `[2,0]` and `["Lemon", "Kiwi"]` and then passes them to splice as comma seperated arguments like

```
fruits.splice(2,0,"Lemon", "Kiwi");
```

which modify the array like below

```
["Banana", "Orange", "Lemon", "Kiwi", "Apple", "Mango"]
```

Answer (score 8):

As per the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) from function signature:

**`array.splice(start[, deleteCount[, item1[, item2[, ...]]]])`**

In B:

```
fruits.splice(...[2,0].concat(["Lemon", "Kiwi"]));
```

Because `[2,0].concat(["Lemon", "Kiwi"])` means `[2,0,"Lemon", "Kiwi"]`.

So `fruits.splice(...[2,0,"Lemon", "Kiwi"]);` becomes `fruits.splice(2,0,"Lemon", "Kiwi");` using the spread operator(`...`).

Above code you are saying add `"Lemon"`, `"Kiwi"`, from index `2` witho deleting 0 items.

In this case `2` is `start` index, `deleteCount` is `0`, and `item1` is `"Lemon"`, `item2` is `"Kiwi"`.

Now in A:

```
fruits.splice(2,0,["Lemon", "Kiwi"]);
```

You are saying add `["Lemon", "Kiwi"]`, from index `2` with deleting 0 items. In this case `2` is `start` index, `deleteCount` is `0`, and `item1` is `["Lemon", "Kiwi"]`.

Answer (score 8):

All other answers correctly describe [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method and spread operator behavior, but none tries to correct your misunderstanding about the result.

What you are actually seeing, is the *return value* of [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method, which is ***an array containing the removed elements***, which in both your method calls, are none. That's why you get an empty array as the result.

To see the behavior of calling [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method, you need to log the `fruits` array after each call (not the *return value* of the method), which in your case is not so much useful, because your expectations about the `fruits` array does not hold in the second call.

Answer (score 6):

First of all you need to understand how splice works

> array.splice(start[, deleteCount[, item1[, item2[, ...]]]])

it takes start(starting index from zero), number of elements to be deleted, and rest any arguments will be added at that starting index.

Now you are clear with splice, so let go step by step for clearer understanding of those statments.

The following statement

```
fruits.splice(...[2,0].concat(["Lemon", "Kiwi"]));
```

after concatenation becomes

```
fruits.splice(...[2,0,"Lemon", "Kiwi"]);
```

after spread it becomes

```
fruits.splice(2,0,"Lemon", "Kiwi");
```

then splice will take fruits from index 2 and delete nothing(as given zero) and add rest of the arguments ie., "Lemon" and "Kiwi"

So You get `["Banana", "Orange", "Lemon", "Kiwi", "Apple", "Mango"]`

Where as in

```
fruits.splice(2,0,["Lemon", "Kiwi"]);
```

the splice will take fruits from index 2 and delete nothing(again as given zero) and add rest of the arguments i.e, "["Lemon", "Kiwi"]"

So you get `["Banana", "Orange", ["Lemon", "Kiwi"], "Apple", "Mango"]`

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

Without using spread, B is:

```
fruits.splice( 2, 0, "Lemon", "Kiwi" );
```

The `concat` is a bit confusing, it could also have been written as:

```
fruits.splice( ...[ 2, 0 ], ...[ "Lemon", "Kiwi" ] );
```

Or:

```
fruits.splice( ...[ 2, 0, "Lemon", "Kiwi" ] );
```